# How to define and initialize variables in drools rule

Tags: java-8, drools

I am using drools 6.1. I have a drool file. I want to do something like this.

```
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getCurrentDate;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getDate;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getMonthNameFromInt;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getExpiryDate;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getEmailDate;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getWeekOfYear;
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.LicenseCredential;
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.Learner;
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.CsvFileWriter;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

global com.softech.vu360.autoalert.CsvFileWriter learnerCsvFileWriter;

function void processData(LicenseCredential licenseCredential, CsvFileWriter learnerCsvFileWritern, LocalDate expiryDate, LocalDate emailDate){

    Learner learner = new Learner();
    learner.setFirstName(licenseCredential.getFirstName());
    ...
    learnerCsvFileWriter.add(learner);

}

rule "Renewal alert for 60 days"
when
    licenseCredential : LicenseCredential()

    $courseCompletionDate : licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate()
    $renewalDeadlineDay : licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay()
    $renewalDeadlineMonth : licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth()
    $currentDate : getCurrentDate()
    $dayOfMonth : $courseCompletionDate.getDate()
    $month : $courseCompletionDate.getMonth()
    $expiryDate : getExpiryDate(licenseCredential)
    $emailDate : getEmailDate(2, licenseCredential)
    $localDate : LocalDate.now()
    $intRenewalDeadlineDay : Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineDay)
    $intRenewalDeadlineMonth : Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineMonth)

    (
        eval($renewalDeadlineDay == "0" && $renewalDeadlineMonth == "0") && 
        eval($currentDate.after(getDate(2, $dayOfMonth, $month + 1))) && 
        eval($currentDate.before(getDate(1, $dayOfMonth, $month + 1 ))) &&
        eval(getWeekOfYear($localDate.toString()) == getWeekOfYear($emailDate.toString()))
     ) ||
    (
        eval($currentDate.after(getDate(2, $intRenewalDeadlineDay, $intRenewalDeadlineMonth))) &&
        eval($currentDate.before(getDate(1, $intRenewalDeadlineDay, $intRenewalDeadlineMonth))) &&
        eval(getWeekOfYear($localDate.toString()) == getWeekOfYear($emailDate.toString())) 
    )
then
    System.out.println("Rule For 60 Days Called");      
    processData(licenseCredential, learnerCsvFileWriter, $expiryDate, $emailDate);
end
```

I want to declare local variables in my loop. LicenseCredential is a list basically. When I run this rule I get errors that

```
 text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate'], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=71, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay'], Message [id=3, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=72, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth'], Message [id=4, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=73, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'getCurrentDate'], Message [id=5, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=74, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType '$courseCompletionDate.getDate'], Message [id=6, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=75, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType '$courseCompletionDate.getMonth'], Message [id=7, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=76, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'getExpiryDate'], Message [id=8, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=77, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'getEmailDate'], Message [id=9, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=78, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'LocalDate.now'], Message [id=10, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=79, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Integer.valueOf'], Message [id=11, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=80, column=0
   text=Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Integer.valueOf'], Message [id=12, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=36, column=0
```

If i put semicolon at the end of each variable like

```
$courseCompletionDate : licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate();
    $renewalDeadlineDay : licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay();
    $renewalDeadlineMonth : licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth();
    $currentDate : getCurrentDate();
    $dayOfMonth : $courseCompletionDate.getDate();
    $month : $courseCompletionDate.getMonth();
    $expiryDate : getExpiryDate(licenseCredential);
    $emailDate : getEmailDate(2, licenseCredential);
    $localDate : LocalDate.now();
    $intRenewalDeadlineDay : Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineDay);
    $intRenewalDeadlineMonth : Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineMonth);
```

and run the rule I get errors that

```
$renewalDeadlineDay cannot be resolved to a variable
$renewalDeadlineMonth cannot be resolved to a variable
$currentDate cannot be resolved
$dayOfMonth cannot be resolved to a variable
$month cannot be resolved to a variable
$currentDate cannot be resolved
$dayOfMonth cannot be resolved to a variable
$month cannot be resolved to a variable
$localDate cannot be resolved
$emailDate cannot be resolved
$currentDate cannot be resolved
$intRenewalDeadlineDay cannot be resolved to a variable
$intRenewalDeadlineMonth cannot be resolved to a variable
$currentDate cannot be resolved
$intRenewalDeadlineDay cannot be resolved to a variable
$intRenewalDeadlineMonth cannot be resolved to a variable
$localDate cannot be resolved
$emailDate cannot be resolved
$expiryDate cannot be resolved to a variable
$emailDate cannot be resolved to a variable], Message [id=14, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=-1, column=0
```

How can I define local variables. How can I do this ?

Thanks

**---------------------------------
Edit**

Here how I am firing rules

```
List<LicenseCredential> objectList = dao.select();
BusinessRuleProcessor ruleProcessor = (BusinessRuleProcessor)context.getBean("businessRuleProcessor");
ruleProcessor.configureAndApplyRulesOnObject(objectList);

public class BusinessRuleProcessor {
    ....
    public void configureAndApplyRulesOnObject(List<LicenseCredential> objectList){

        statelessKieSession.setGlobal("learnerCsvFileWriter", csvFileWriter);
        statelessKieSession.execute(objectList);

    }
}
```

**--------------
Edit2:**

Tried this and getting errors

```
rule "Renewal alert for 60 days"
when
    licenseCredential : LicenseCredential()

    $licenseCredentialCC : LicenseCredential($courseCompletionDate : courseCompletionDate)
    $licenseCredentialRDLD : LicenseCredential($renewalDeadlineDay : renewalDeadlineDay)
    $licenseCredentialRDLM : LicenseCredential($renewalDeadlineMonth : renewalDeadlineMonth)
    $licenseCredentialCD : LicenseCredential($currentDate : getCurrentDate())
    $licenseCredentialDOM : LicenseCredential($dayOfMonth : $licenseCredentialCC.getDate())
    $licenseCredentialM : LicenseCredential($month : $licenseCredentialCC.getMonth())
    $licenseCredentialEXD : LicenseCredential($expiryDate : getExpiryDate(licenseCredential))
    $licenseCredentialEMD : LicenseCredential($emailDate : getEmailDate(2, licenseCredential))
    $licenseCredentialLD : LicenseCredential($localDate : LocalDate.now())
    $licenseCredentialIRDLD : LicenseCredential($intRenewalDeadlineDay :  Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLD))
    $licenseCredentialIRDLM : LicenseCredential($intRenewalDeadlineMonth : Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLM))

    (
        eval($renewalDeadlineDay == "0" && $renewalDeadlineMonth == "0") && 
        eval($currentDate.after(getDate(2, $dayOfMonth, $month + 1))) && 
        eval($currentDate.before(getDate(1, $dayOfMonth, $month + 1 ))) &&
        eval(getWeekOfYear($localDate.toString()) == getWeekOfYear($emailDate.toString()))
     ) ||
    (
        eval($currentDate.after(getDate(2, $intRenewalDeadlineDay, $intRenewalDeadlineMonth))) &&
        eval($currentDate.before(getDate(1, $intRenewalDeadlineDay, $intRenewalDeadlineMonth))) &&
        eval(getWeekOfYear($localDate.toString()) == getWeekOfYear($emailDate.toString())) 
    )
then
    System.out.println("Rule For 60 Days Called");      
    processData(licenseCredential, learnerCsvFileWriter, $expiryDate, $emailDate);
end
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoalert-ksession-stateless': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'autoalert-kbase' while setting bean property 'kBase'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoalert-kbase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=76, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression $licenseCredentialCC.getDate():
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.LicenseCredential.getDate()]
[Near : {... $licenseCredentialCC.getDate() ....}]
                              ^
[Line: 76, Column: 2]], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=76, column=0
   text=Unable to analyze expression '$licenseCredentialCC.getDate()'], Message [id=3, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=77, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression $licenseCredentialCC.getMonth():
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.LicenseCredential.getMonth()]
[Near : {... $licenseCredentialCC.getMonth() ....}]
                              ^
[Line: 77, Column: 2]], Message [id=4, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=77, column=0
   text=Unable to analyze expression '$licenseCredentialCC.getMonth()'], Message [id=5, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=78, column=0
   text=Variables can not be used inside bindings. Variable   [licenseCredential] is being used in binding 'getExpiryDate(licenseCredential)'], Message [id=6, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=79, column=0
   text=Variables can not be used inside bindings. Variable [licenseCredential] is being used in binding 'getEmailDate(2, licenseCredential)'], Message [id=7, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=81, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLD):
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Integer.valueOf(com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.LicenseCredential)]
[Near : {... Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLD ....}]
                 ^
[Line: 81, Column: 2]], Message [id=8, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=81, column=0
   text=Unable to analyze expression 'Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLD)'], Message [id=9, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=82, column=0
   text=Unable to Analyse Expression Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLM):
    [Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Integer.valueOf(com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.LicenseCredential)]
    [Near : {... Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLM ....}]
                 ^
    [Line: 82, Column: 2]], Message [id=10, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=82, column=0
   text=Unable to analyze expression 'Integer.valueOf($licenseCredentialRDLM)'], Message [id=11, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=60, column=0
   text=[ function processDataprocessData (line:60): learnerCsvFileWriter cannot be resolved
 ]],     Message [id=12, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=68, column=0
       text=Rule Compilation error The import drools.rules.ProcessData cannot be resolved
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int
The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int
The method getDate(int, int, int) in the type Utility is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object, Object)
The method getDate(int, int, int) in the type Utility is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object, Object)
$expiryDate cannot be resolved to a variable
$emailDate cannot be resolved to a variable], Message [id=13, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=-1, column=0
```

---

Edit 3

```
rule "Renewal alert for 60 days"
when
    licenseCredential : LicenseCredential()

    $licenseCredential1 : LicenseCredential($courseCompletionDate : courseCompletionDate)
    $licenseCredential2 : LicenseCredential($renewalDeadlineDay : renewalDeadlineDay)
    $licenseCredential3 : LicenseCredential($renewalDeadlineMonth : renewalDeadlineMonth)
    $licenseCredential4 : LicenseCredential($currentDate : getCurrentDate())
    //$licenseCredential5 : LicenseCredential($dayOfMonth : licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getDate())
    //$licenseCredential6 : LicenseCredential($month : licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getMonth())
    //$licenseCredential7 : LicenseCredential($expiryDate : getExpiryDate(licenseCredential))
    //$licenseCredential8 : LicenseCredential($emailDate : getEmailDate(2, licenseCredential))
    $licenseCredential9 : LicenseCredential($localDate : LocalDate.now())

    (
        eval($renewalDeadlineDay == "0" && $renewalDeadlineMonth == "0") && 
        eval($currentDate.after(getDate(2, licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getDate(), licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getMonth() + 1))) && 
        eval($currentDate.before(getDate(1, licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getDate(), licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getMonth() + 1 ))) &&
        eval(getWeekOfYear($localDate.toString()) == getWeekOfYear(getEmailDate(2, licenseCredential).toString()))
     ) ||
    (
        eval($currentDate.after(getDate(2, Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineDay), Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineMonth)))) &&
        eval($currentDate.before(getDate(1, Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineDay), Integer.valueOf($renewalDeadlineMonth)))) &&
        eval(getWeekOfYear($localDate.toString()) == getWeekOfYear(getEmailDate(2, licenseCredential).toString())) 
    )

then
    System.out.println("Rule For 60 Days Called");      
    processData(licenseCredential, learnerCsvFileWriter, 2);
end
```

**------------------
Edit 4**

Here is my LicenseCredential class

```
public class LicenseCredential {
    private String learnerName;
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String learnerEmailAddress;
    private String userGUID;
    private Integer vu360UserId;
    private Integer courseId;
    protected String courseName;
    protected Date courseCompletionDate;
    private Integer credentialId;
    protected String officialLicenseName;
    private String shortLicenseName;
    private String renewalDeadLineType;
    private String renewalFrequency;
    private String renewalDeadlineDay;
    private String renewalDeadlineMonth; 
    private String hardDeadLineYear;
    private String staggeredBy;
    private String staggeredTo;
    protected String jurisdiction;
    protected String storefrontURL;

    //  setters and getters
}
```

Here is my Utility class

```
public class Utility {
    public static Date getDate(int monthsToBeSubtracted, int date, int month) throws Exception{
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();        
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH)-monthsToBeSubtracted);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, getCurrentDate().getYear()+1900);
        return c.getTime();
    }

    public static Date getCurrentDate(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        return c.getTime();
    }

    public static int getWeekOfYear(String date) throws Exception{
        Date currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
        String weekOfYear = new SimpleDateFormat("w").format(currentDate);
        return Integer.valueOf(weekOfYear);
    }    

    public static LocalDate getExpiryDate(LicenseCredential licenseCredential) {

        if (licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay() == "0" && licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth() == "0") {
            Date courseCompletionDate = licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate();
            ...
            return expiryDate;
        } else {
            ...
            return expiryDate;
        }

    }
}
```

Previously this rule was like this

```
rule "Renewal alert for 60 days"
when
    licenseCredential : LicenseCredential()
    (
        eval(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay() == "0" && licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth() == "0") && 
        eval(getCurrentDate().after(getDate(2, licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getDate(), licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getMonth()+1))) && 
        eval(getCurrentDate().before(getDate(1, licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getDate(), licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getMonth()+1))) 
     ) ||
    (
        eval(getCurrentDate().after(getDate(2, Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay()), Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth()) ))) &&
        eval(getCurrentDate().before(getDate(1, Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay()), Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth() )))) 
    )
then
    System.out.println("Rule For 60 Days Called");      
    processData(licenseCredential, "templates/Template.vm", "60Days", messageProducer);
end
```

Comment: Have you imported `LicenseCredential` into your DRL file?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but can you post your **full** DRL file?

Comment: @I.K. just did, now check

Comment: Your rule definition is faulty. You cannot have function pointers as you have defined them in a DRL file.

Comment: @I.K. What do you mean by `You cannot have function pointers as you have defined them in a DRL file` ? I have a function in my drl file , I didn,t show it. Let me edit and add a function declaration.

Comment: @I.K.This is right I am drools newbie but I read tutorials. Here is what I read at JBoss site `We recommend using property access (age) over using getters explicitly (getAge()) because of performance enhancements through field indexing.`  I also corrected the error. Now no error is showing.  I don't know a lot about writing rules but at-least you can guide me about good practices. I am posting my new code which is working now. I don't know how good it is but at-least you can give me direction that how can I improve my rule. Thanks

Comment: Well, if it is working - where is the problem. - But this isn't how a rule should be written, and you didn't read the right tutorials. - Can you describe *verbally* (absolutely no code, please) what this rule should achieve?

Comment: @I.K.Ofcourse I can. Basically as you know that I have a list that I am inserting in my rule file. Basically I have previously 3 rules. One is `"Renewal alert for 60 days"` and others two were `"Renewal alert for 90 days"` and `"Renewal alert for 30 days"`. Previously what these rules did, they check learner credentials in each `licenseCredential `. Check whether their course is expiring or not and send email before `90, 60 or 30 Days`. Now I have to change `60 days rule`. In this rule I have to write CSV file for learners whose course is expiring after 60 days. Hope you understand.

Comment: To be honest, previously I didn't write these rules. These rules were written by someone else. Now I am taking care of his code.  Of-course I want my rules to be of standard, that's why I asked you to guide me. And Thanks for your help. I am really glad that you told me about how rule should be written and the rule that I posted does not follow standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know what the rule should evaluate, this is more like the style your rule should be written. I don't know how LicenseCredential is declared, nor do I know those Util.getXyz functions, so this may not work. Also, I've skipped the last condition.

```
rule "Renewal alert for 60 days"
when
licenseCredential : LicenseCredential(
      $courseCompletionDate : courseCompletionDate,
      $renewalDeadlineDay : renewalDeadlineDay == "0",
      $renewalDeadlineMonth : renewalDeadlineMonth == "0",
      $currentDate : currentDate after 
              getDate(2, $courseCompletionDate.getDate(),
                         $courseCompletionDate.getMonth()+1 ),
              && before
              getDate(1, $courseCompletionDate.getDate(),
                         $courseCompletionDate.getMonth()+1 ) )
then
    System.out.println("Rule For 60 Days Called");      
    processData(licenseCredential, learnerCsvFileWriter, 2);
end
```

Comment: Hope you understand that actually I am trying to achieve writing csv file. For this I added global list variable. For learners who come in then part I added those learners to my list. And then use that list to write csv file.And also I want to write good rule, mean the way in which rule should be written. Thanks

Comment: Writing data to a file is not the problem: you'll have to select the data correctly. I don't know the types of the fields in class `LicenseCredential` and what they mean, and I don't know what all these static methods from class `Utility` do - so I'm not sure whether everything I wrote is correct. But now you have a sample of a rule as it *should be written*.

Comment: I have edited my code. You can see there LicenseCredential class. What fields do class have and what are the types. Anyway thanks for your help. You are right that I have sample at-least :) Thanks for your help.